# onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/,/g,'.')" with php echo' '

Tags: php, javascript

In input field need to replace `,` with `.`.

With HTM such code is working `onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/,/g,'.')"`

But need to use in php (with echo) like this:

```
echo '<input type="text" name="amount_1" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/,/g,'.')" style="width:53px;"></input>';
```

With php does not work. If use this `this.value.replace(/,/g,/./)` then `,` is replaced with `/./`.

Tried `(/,/g,"/./")`, `(/,/g,/"."/)`, `(/,/g,.)` nothing works (I mean `,` does not change to `.`).

Any ideas?

Comment: What you mean about "does not work"? Errors or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to escape the `'` with a backslash in your PHP code.

```
echo '<input type="text" name="amount_1" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/,/g,\'.\')" style="width:53px;"></input>';
```

Otherwise you are cuting your string into to pices an put it together with the point.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly I needed. I did not know how to escape.